# Plotting in layers in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to plot individual regression lines for all of my experimental subjects (n=40) on the same plot where I show the overall regression line.

I can do the plots separately with ggplot, but I haven't found a way to superpose them on the same graph.

I can illustrate what I did with the iris data frame:

```
   #first plot
   ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   stat_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
   theme_classic() 

   # second plot, grouped by species
   ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, colour =Species)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   stat_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) + 
   theme_classic()

   # and I've been trying things like this:
   ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   stat_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
   theme_classic() + 
   geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, colour =Species))) + 
   stat_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
   theme_classic()
```

which returns the message "Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?", so I get that this is not the right way to combine them, but what is?

How can I combine both graphs in one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, they were very helpful!

Is there a way to separately code the colour of the regression lines? I'd like to try it with all lines in black (or grey scale) except for the overall "all" or "together" line in red, for instance. 
As it is I seem to have to follow one aes pattern for all lines (my attempts to change them have given me the "Warning message: Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: colour" or  "Error: `mapping` must be created by `aes()`"
Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 1):

Repeat the whole data and set Species to be something else (`"Together"`) in example below. Attach the repeated data to the original data and just call the second plot.

```
d1 = iris
d2 = rbind(d1, transform(d1, Species = "Together"))
ggplot(d2, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, colour =Species)) + 
    stat_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
    geom_point(data = d1) +
    theme_classic()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @d.b's answer, consider expanding the data frame with `rbind`, assigning an "All" category for *Species* and adjust for factor levels (so *All* shows at top on legend):

```
new_species_level <- c("All", unique(as.character(iris$Species)))

iris_expanded <- rbind(transform(iris, Species=factor("All", levels=new_species_level)),
                       transform(iris, Species=factor(Species, levels=new_species_level)))

ggplot(iris_expanded, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   stat_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) + 
   theme_classic()
```

[image: Plot Output]